# How to add user created .mat files to the search path after compilation

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, mcc

How can I allow user to add additional dependenies **after** the source code was compiled with mcc.

I was thinking about an empty folder next to the executable, where the users can add the needed .mat-files, but I can't add the folder path to my executable (since addpath is not allowed in deployed applications).

Any ideas?

Comment: You make the file an input to your mcc, I guess

Comment: The files are not available at compilation time, so I can't add them to mcc and I want to avoid to compile the model, because there is a single new .mat file.

Comment: You can't do what you ask. The closest thing is making the code read from an specific folder everytime and make the user change the .mat file of that folder

Comment: The MCC creates a closed package that cannot be modified. They want you to be able to distribute your code, but they don't want others to have a free version of MATLAB. If I could change your code to do what I wanted it to do, I would have a full copy of MATLAB without paying for it... Thus, what you want to do is not possible by design. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes that your code can be customised by data contained in one or more .mat files at runtime.*

You can point your code to look at a folder where the optional `.mat` file(s) would be located.

For example in the users home folder with a sub folder being the name of your application (or in the local app data) or whereever...

If you want it in a sub folder where the `exe` is, you can do this as well, you find the `exe` path using (on windows):

```
[status, result] = system('path');
installpath = char(regexpi(result, 'Path=(.*?);', 'tokens', 'once'));
fprintf ( 'The exe install path is "%s"\n', installpath );
```

Then your code looks to load for example:

```
file2load = fullfile ( installpath, 'subFolder', 'runtimeCustomisation.mat' )
if exist ( file2load, 'file' ) == 2
  "doSomething with the file"
end
```

Or something like that.

Recall that this is for dependencies which are `.mat` files only.